# How to dynamically add polylines from an arraylist

Tags: android, google-maps, dynamically-generated, google-polyline

I have an

```
places = ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>
```

I am adding LatLng points into the inner ArrayList and then I have a for loop that loops and adds polylines to the map.. except it doesnt do that...
How can I add polylines dynamically to the GoogleMap? I checked whether or not places was being populated and it is.

Thanks in advance.

```
ArrayList<Polyline> pl = new ArrayList<Polyline>();                 
for(int i =0; i<places.size(); i++){
        pl.add(mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(places.get(i))));
        Log.e("size of places", "size of places is " + places.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have list of latitude an longitudes in your List, you can use the below to draw lines.

```
List<LatLng> points = decodePoly(_path); // list of latlng
for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {
  LatLng src = points.get(i);
  LatLng dest = points.get(i + 1);

  // mMap is the Map Object
  Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(
    new PolylineOptions().add(
      new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
      new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude)
    ).width(2).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true)
  );
}
```

the above worked for me in my application

Comment: @Raghunandan Hey I need some help for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android/20916931#20916931)I am bit confuse with your above answer.pls help me

Comment: @chintankhetiya what is the confusion?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era can we talk here if you don't mind so i can explain you

Answer (score 17):

Adding multiple points in map using polyline and arraylist

```
ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

// Adding points to ArrayList
coordList.add(new LatLng(0, 0);
coordList.add(new LatLng(1, 1);
coordList.add(new LatLng(2, 2);
// etc...

// Find map fragment. This line work only with support library
GoogleMap gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

// Create polyline options with existing LatLng ArrayList
polylineOptions.addAll(coordList);
polylineOptions
 .width(5)
 .color(Color.RED);

// Adding multiple points in map using polyline and arraylist
gMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the `places` variable you have because places need to be all the locations in the line and not just 1 point.

So assuming places is `ArrayList<LatLng>` then by doing `places.get(i)` you are only giving one point and not the whole list of points;

Comment: places is ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> so get(i) is the first arraylist of LatLng's

Comment: are you sure there is actually something in the list then?

Comment: It draws one route and only one route. I have changed my code to this 

`Polyline p1 = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(places.get(0)).geodesic(true));
    p1.setColor(Color.RED);    
   Polyline p2 = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(places.get(1)).geodesic(true));
    p2.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
   Polyline p3 = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(places.get(2)).geodesic(true));
    p3.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
   Polyline p4 = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(places.get(3)).geodesic(true));
    p4.setColor(Color.GREEN);`

and draws the green one