# How to smooth out polyline directions on Android Google Maps API?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have polylines working for directions form two locations on Android Google Maps API, however, you can tell that the corners are jagged and not smooth. Are there any steps to take to smooth these lines out to appear more natural (like on google's own maps site)

**Below is the class that is called with appropriate parameters to create the polylines**

```
public class GetDirectionsData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

String googlePlacesData;
GoogleMap mMap;
String url;
LatLng latlng;


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
    mMap = (GoogleMap)objects[0];
    url = (String)objects[1];
    latlng = (LatLng)objects[2];

    DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
    try {
        googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return googlePlacesData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s){
    String[] directionsList;

    DataParser parser = new DataParser();
    directionsList = parser.parseDirections(s);
    displayDirections(directionsList);
}

public void displayDirections(String[] directionsList){
    int count = directionsList.length;
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
        options.color(Color.rgb(0,179,253));
        options.width(15);
        options.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(directionsList[i]));
        mMap.addPolyline(options);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would look into changing the join type for your polyline. I am unfamiliar with the API, but here is a link I think you might find helpful. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/JointType

Comment: @KeeganTeetaert that seems to be on the right track and I added 'options.JoinType(2)' and tried 'options.JoinType(JointType.Rounded)' however, neither changed anything

Comment: Also look at the cap (default is "butt") but "square" ("squared off after extending half the stroke width beyond ") or "round".

Comment: Have you had a look at:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508383/google-map-api-making-lines-smoother-when-bending/26508612#26508612

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add all directions as one polyline, not separate polyline for separate direction: use something like

```
public void displayDirections(String[] directionsList){
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
    options.color(Color.rgb(0,179,253));
    options.width(15);
    int count = directionsList.length;
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        options.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(directionsList[i]));
    }
    mMap.addPolyline(options);
}
```

instead of

```
public void displayDirections(String[] directionsList){
    int count = directionsList.length;
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
        options.color(Color.rgb(0,179,253));
        options.width(15);
        options.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(directionsList[i]));
        mMap.addPolyline(options);
    }
}
```

because `JointType` affects points of polyline, not separate polylines.