# Google Map Polyline Issue

Tags: android, google-maps

Having an issue with polyline. I have lat n long in main activity. Have to draw a path with given latitude and longitude but couldn't find a proper way to pass the data to polyline. Does Polyline takes array list? plz help me out. a big thank you in advance.
Here is the code.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(latitude));

    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(longitude));

    latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

    myLatLong = new double[]{getLatitude(),getLongitude()};
}
```

and here is MapsActivity code.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .clickable(true)
            .add(
                    new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321),
                    new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592),
                    new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891),
                    new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217),
                    new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248),
                    new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309)));
}
```

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25978663/1281180)

Comment: I have tried sir. but issue is still same.