# How to paint Polyline correctly

Tags: android, sqlite, polyline

I'm working on android polyline with latitude and longitude but the points join me as
already try others [How to dynamically add polylines from an arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311076/how-to-dynamically-add-polylines-from-an-arraylist)

[image: so he paints]

```
            pointss =  getCoordenadas();
            for (int x = 0; x < pointss.size(); x++){
                polylineOptions.add(pointss.get(x));
            }
            mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

```
public List<LatLng> getAllPositions(String co, String lo) {
    List<LatLng> positionList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    FallasHelper falHelper = new FallasHelper(getActivity());
    cursor = falHelper.Select(co,lo);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        double latitude = cursor.getDouble(0);
        double longitude = cursor.getDouble(1);

        LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        positionList.add(newLatLng);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return positionList;
}
```